# How to add new Pivot Item in loading event of the pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add new pivot item each time user swipes the pivot item. Add new item and remove the old one. (Pivot Headers and Items are correctly bonded at first load).

I have below code in Loading event of pivot

```
private void Pivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ++App.SuraID;
                p = new PageViewModel();

                //this.pv.DataContext = p.Pages;
                this.pv.ItemsSource = p.Pages;
                p.OnPropertyChanged("Pages");
                pv.UpdateLayout();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

and PageViewModel constructor

```
public PageViewModel()
        {
            Pages = new ObservableCollection<ArticlePage>();
            DataSource ds = new DataSource();
            List<ArabicTextWithTranslation> ls = null;
            Chapter ch = ds.getChapter(App.SuraID);
            ls = ds.getArabicTextWithTranslation(ch);
            if (App.SuraID == 1) // Just to make Pivot on first run
            {
                Pages.Add(new ArticlePage() { Header = ch.SuraName, ArticleList = new ObservableCollection<Article> { new Article() { MyChapter = ch } } });
                Pages.Add(new ArticlePage() { Header = ch.SuraName, ArticleList = new ObservableCollection<Article> { new Article() { MyChapter = ch } } });//
            }
            else
                Pages.Add(new ArticlePage() { Header = ch.SuraName, ArticleList = new ObservableCollection<Article> { new Article() { MyChapter = ch } } });//
        }
```

How can I add new pivot item to pivot control?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to add and remove pivot items from the pivot control!
But there is a cool helper class that you can use to make it simple... take a look at the detailed example explained here: http://www.ree7.fr/blog/2014/01/data-binding-pivotitem-visibility-an-helper/

If you want some more control, you can do it on your own, a working example of this can be seen in my github project here: https://github.com/Depechie/GF13/blob/master/AppCreativity.GentseFeesten.WP8/AppCreativity.GentseFeesten.WP8/View/MainPage.xaml.cs#L51
Here I add or remove pivot items from the collection depending on what the user selected on the page.